# Split file names that consists either of 2 or 3 components

Tags: regex, split

I need to extract artist, title and comments components from file names,
below an example of artist - title, artist - title (comments)

```
ADNY - Omnipotent.flac
Community Recordings - Magic Circle (Drums In Space Mix).flac
```

This regex only matches number 2, not number 1

```
(^.*)\s-\s(.*)\s(\(.*\))

Community Recordings
Magic Circle
(Drums In Space Mix)
```

If I append a ? at the end of it, both are matched but for number 2 the comment is part of the title:

```
(^.*)\s-\s(.*)\s(\(.*\))?

ADNY
Omnipotent.flac

Community Recordings
Magic Circle (Drums In Space Mix).flac
```

How can I split components accounting that the file name might have a comment or not ?

(to get something like this)

```
ADNY
Omnipotent.flac

Community Recordings
Magic Circle
(Drums In Space Mix).flac
```

(using .NET regex flavor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your components, try the regex below.  Since you mentioned you are using the .NET flavor, I chose to use Name'd capturing groups:

```
^(?<Artist>.*?)\s*-\s*(?<Title>.*?(?=\s+\(|\.))(?:\s*\((?<Description>[^)]+))?
```

I also chose to omit the parentheses from the Description, as well as the file extension; although they could be included if you want them

Here is another regex that includes the file type:

```
^(?<Artist>.*?)\s*-\s*(?<Title>.*?(?=\s+\(|\.))(?:\s*\((?<Description>[^)]+)\))?\.(?<FileType>\S+)
```

If you want to include the parentheses and/or the "dot", merely move them into the capturing groups

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the trailing space optional as well:

```
(^.*)\s-\s(.*)\s(\(.*\))?
              ^^---
```

If a song has a comment, then there's a space:

```
Foo - Bar (Baz).flac
         ^--- space
```

but then where's no comment, there's no space:

```
Foo - Bar.flac
         ^--no space
```

Your regex is requiring that space be present, so it'll never match the comment-less versions. Try

```
(^.*)\s-\s(.*)(\s\(.*\))?
              ^^^--- swap positions
```

instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same result with it.